# Inject InjectionPoint in Generic Class to get the actual class type?

Tags: java, generics, cdi

in my JSF 2.3 project(wildfly 19 app. server) I have a generic EntityService class which takes two type parameters. The EntityService class also injects another class GenericEntityService. GenericEntityService is a @Stateless bean which uses the EntityManager to do the real work (find entity, update entity, delete entity, insert entity...)

```
@Dependent
public class EntityService<T, ID> {

    @Inject
    private GenericEntityService<T, ID> entityService;
    private Class<T> entityClass;
    
    @Inject
    private void entityClass(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) injectionPoint.getType();
        Class<T> entityClass = (Class<T>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }
    
    public T find(ID id) {
        return entityService.find(entityClass, id);
    }
    
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityService.findAll(entityClass);
    }

  [...]
}
```

Because the find method of the EntityManager needs a class type as an argument, I injected an InjectionPoint in the entityClass method to get the actual "entity class type" and pass this as an argument to the GenericEntityService methods.

Is there anything wrong with this approach to get the class type from the type argument ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your entityClass function does not get called, it does not fill your entityClass field, so it will always be null when called.

You may use a similar approach, avoiding the need of an injection point, using getter method that uses the parameterized type. Your code would change to:

```
@Dependent
public abstract class EntityService<T, ID> {

    @Inject
    private GenericEntityService<T, ID> entityService;

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public synchronized Class<T> getEntityClass() {
        if (entityClass == null) {
            entityClass = inferEntityClass(getClass());
        }
        return entityClass;
    }

    private Class<?> inferEntityClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        // This code should be safer
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
        return (Class<T>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public T find(ID id) {
        return entityService.find(getEntityClass(), id);
    }
    // ...
}
```

On a side note, unrelated: I didn't get the reason why you should create another layer of beans instead of calling EntityManager directly from your EntityService. Please note that some features that would justify this architecture, such as transaction control, are already present on CDI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First: the container calls my initializer method entityClass, therefore injecting the InjectionPoint (it works using wildfly 19). Second: I have to use composition here because I cant have state on my stateless bean. I tried the "all in one class" approach but this doesnt work with stateless beans (according to the docs stateless beans get pooled and its not guranteed that I get a fresh instance for every @Inject or the same instance for my method calls)

Comment: I would remove the need of the previous call to the initializer method, as described in the code at the answer, as the strategy avoids one more call (and injections) on CDI provider and depends only on the compiled class. About the composition, what stale data would be kept in your service? One more thing: did I answer your question?